# Is there a solution for required mutually exclusive arguments listed as optional in help section?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So using argparse I created a mutually exclusive group which has two items. One of the must be always passed, so I created the group with `required=True`.

It's properly working, If I don't call the script with either of them, it will fail with `error: one of the arguments --foo --bar is required`

However, the problem comes when I just run it with `-h` or `--help`. It's listing these parameters as optional, but they are not.

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --foo                 foo
  --bar                 bar

required arguments:
  --alice               alice
```

Is there any solution to list them as required? As `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` does not support the `title` parameter, I cannot do something like `add_mutually_exclusive_group('must pick one', required=True)`

Comment: They *aren't* required - if both appeared under `required arguments` that would indicate that both are *simultaneously* required, which isn't true. You could add a description to each individual argument, noting that it's mutually exclusive with the other one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue17218) in python's issue tracker, however there is a simple workaround for it.

Simply create a titled group and add your mutually exclusive group to that one:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g1 = parser.add_argument_group(title='Foo Bar Group', description='One of these options must be chosen.')
g2 = g1.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
g2.add_argument('--foo',help='Foo help')
g2.add_argument('--bar',help='Bar help')
```

Courtesy of [Paul](https://bugs.python.org/issue17218#msg216761).

Comment: The error behavior is inconsistent.  For example, if one ONLY uses a single required parameter group that is mutually exclusive, the error given when neither are supplied is what one would expect (util:  error:  one of the arguments -abc -xyz is required).  However if you have a required parameter group plus another single required parameter configured, only the single required parameter is listed when none of the parameters are supplied (util: error: the following arguments are required: -qrs).  Parameters -abc and -xyz aren't mentioned as required.  (Tested under 3.7.3)

Comment: @AlanW. very interesting observation! I don't know how to fix it currently, since the answer itself was kind of a hack I'm not sure whether this can be achieved currently. You called for a challenge!